# Why is there a shift in cutoff frequencies of filters, and how to fix it?

Tags: filter, cutoff-frequency, eeg, loading-effect

I am doing a project where I am designing my own EEG circuit. I aim to keep it fairly simple and essentially design my circuit to do two things:

1. Amplification
2. Filtering

I want to design the circuit (the filter specifically) so that it can demonstrate beta-waves from the brain, as it corresponds to an active state which can be achieved without much issues. The range of beta brainwaves is roughly from 12-32 Hz. In my circuit, I have three stages:

1. **An Instrumentation Amplifier:** to amplify the differential input that I will capture with two electrodes that I have. In my case I have made the instrumentation amplifier using three op-amps.
2. **A 2nd Order Bandpass Filter:** to only get the required range of 12-32 Hz and attenuate the other frequencies.
3. **A common-emitter Amplifier:** This stage will give me even more gain. I have no specific gain-requirement as such so long as the output is clear and noise-free on the oscilloscope. I really don't know if this stage is necessary or not, because the instrumentation amplifier can give the gain that we want. I have to have this in my circuit unfortunately because our instructor necessitates us to have at least one stage that involves the use of a MOSFET/BJT, so this stage is there primarily to fulfill this purpose.

My complete circuit looks like this:
[image]

The issue that I am facing is that, the -3 dB cutoff in the AC-sweep of the entire circuit is not exactly the frequency for which the circuit was designed for, vis-a-vis 12 and 32 Hz, they are coming out to be around 10.1 Hz and 38.7 Hz, as you can see here:

This is the maximum gain that is achieved (@20 Hz, 59.6 dB)
[image]

This is the realized cutoff for the high pass filter: (-3 dB @ 10.1 Hz)
[image]

This is the realized cutoff for the low pass filter: (-3 dB @ 38.7 Hz)
[image]

My question is: Why is there a **significant** shift in the cutoff frequency from which the circuit was designed for? Is this due to the loading effect perhaps? What should be done to fix this shift and get it as close to the desired values as possible?

Also, the maximum gain I get is at 20 Hz, is there a reason as to why it is 20 Hz? I have tried out other resistor-capacitor values as well and they also give a maximum at 20 Hz, why is this so?

From my side, I have tried to fix this issue by changing the resistor-capacitor values and trying to get it to the actual values, but this feels more like hit and trial and doesn't guarantee the desired working in case I add some other stage later. How can I tackle this problem? Help is appreciated! Also, please let me know about any general changes I can make to this circuit to make it better without adding too much complexity.

Comment: *The issue that I am facing is that, the -3dB cutoff in the AC-Sweep of the entire circuit is not exactly the frequency for which the circuit was designed for, vis-a-vis 12Hz and 32Hz*. You could show your calculations here for this multistage filter/amplifier.

Comment: If you are building this, it still won't work if you use ceramic capacitors because the only dieelectric that does not change capacitance with DC bias is C0G/NPO. They can change between 30-80%. The values being used are too large to be found in this dieelectric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we treat the two stages (high-pass and low-pass) individually, it will make things clear:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJJURq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here I have recreated your filter stages, and I am feeding them with the same input, to obtain their gain vs. frequency plots:

[image]

Blue is the high-pass, and orange is the low-pass. The brown plot is their sum, which will be overall gain, if they were cascaded.

The first thing to note is that for second order filters (such as the Sallen-Key designs you've used here), the cut-off frequency is deemed to be where gain has dropped to -6dB, not the -3dB figure used with first-order systems. The formula \$f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi RC}\$ for this Sallen-Key design is actually the -6dB frequency.

So before you continue, you must first be clear whether or not you are aiming to position the -3dB points at 12Hz and 32Hz.

In the graph above the top and right green markers show the -6dB point for the high-pass filter (blue), which is at 12Hz, corresponding well to the required cut-off frequency.

The problem is that at this frequency, the other low-pass filter (orange) has already started to attenuate too, at about -1dB. The combined gain from both filters at that frequency will be about -7dB.

It gets worse. Right in the middle of the pass-band, at 20Hz, both filters are attenuating slightly. The brown curve at about 20Hz shows the sum of gains \$(-2.8dB) + (-2.8dB) = -5.6dB\$, which should start to make sense now. By combining the two filters to create a pass-band filter, you actually have a gain of -5.6dB in the centre of that band, not 0dB as I believe you expected.

You must consider the combined (cascaded) gain at the centre frequency, which will necessarily be far below 0dB if the pass-band is so narrow like this. Simultaneously you must establish -6dB (or -3dB) points with respect to that maximum. The bottom and left green markers represents that point, 6dB underneath the peak of the brown curve. As you can see, the frequency there is about 8Hz, not 12Hz. The -3dB point is somewhere around 10Hz, still less than the 12Hz you were expecting.

As for why the center frequency is not 20Hz, and not 22Hz, my intuition tells me that it should be 22Hz, and that your inexact capacitor and resistor values are responsible for this discrepancy. I admit though, there may be some subtle logarithmic nuance I'm overlooking. I'd have to do the maths to be sure, and I won't be doing the maths, for sure.